# Warning: Illegal string offset 'itag' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php

Tags: download, youtube

I used Youtube download script.
I run this script on localhost and this script is working well but when i upload this script and run it an error shows this website:

http://earn2btc.000webhostapp.com/videos/index.php?youtubeid=TKUU2PE9Bdc

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'itag' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php on line 83
Warning: Illegal string offset 'quality' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php on line 84
Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php on line 86

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php on line 87
Warning: Illegal string offset 'expire' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php on line 89
Warning: Illegal string offset 'ipbits' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php on line 90
Warning: Illegal string offset 'ip' in /storage/ssd3/383/3128383/public_html/videos/index.php on line 91

Comment: script this

<?php
 $key = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : "juZN67BA_5w";
 $output = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.$key);
 parse_str($output);
 echo '<p><img src="'. $thumbnail_url .'" border="0" hspace="2" vspace="2"></p>';
 $my_title = $title;
 if(isset($url_encoded_fmt_stream_map)) {
    $my_formats_array = explode(',',$url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
 } else {

Comment: echo '<p>No encoded format stream found.</p>';
    echo '<p>Here is what we got from YouTube:</p>';
    echo $output;
 }
 if (count($my_formats_array) == 0) {
    echo '<p>No format stream map found - was the video id correct?</p>';
    exit;
 }

Comment: $avail_formats[] = '';
 $i = 0;
 $ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality = '0';
 $expire = time();
 foreach($my_formats_array as $format) {
    parse_str($format);
    $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
    $avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
    $type = explode(';',$type);
    $avail_formats[$i]['type'] = $type[0];
    $avail_formats[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' .$sig;
    parse_str(urldecode($url));
    $avail_formats[$i]['expire'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
    $avail_formats[$i]['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
    $avail_formats[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
    $i++;
 }

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < count($avail_formats); $i++) {
$itags = $avail_formats[$i]['itag'];
 echo '<li>' .
            '<span class="itag">' . $itags . 'ssss</span> '.
            '<a href="' . $avail_formats[$i]['url'] . '" class="mime">' . $avail_formats[$i]['type'] . '</a> ' .
            '<small>(' .  $avail_formats[$i]['quality'].'</a>' .
            ')</small>
          </li>';
 }
?>

please help

Comment: Please do not provide details in comments, rather [edit] them into your question. You get better syntax highlighting as well (if formatted as code, use the `{ }` button or indent 4 spaces)